# How to shrink the height and increase the line width of a custom Chartjs horizontal line?

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I am trying to customize a line drawn with the Chartjs 2 plugin, but I need further help. I want to shrink the width of the line and increase the width to the left sothat it fits nice with my setup.

My current setup looks like this:

[image]

The code that is responsible for this look is here:

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
    afterDraw: function(chart) {
        if (typeof chart.config.options.lineAt != 'undefined') {
            var lineAt = chart.config.options.lineAt;
            var ctxPlugin = chart.chart.ctx;
            var xAxe = chart.scales[chart.config.options.scales.xAxes[0].id];
            var yAxe = chart.scales[chart.config.options.scales.yAxes[0].id];

            if(yAxe.min != 0) return;

            ctxPlugin.strokeStyle = "#14646F";
            ctxPlugin.beginPath();
            lineAt = (lineAt - yAxe.min) * (100 / yAxe.max);
            lineAt = (100 - lineAt) / 100 * (yAxe.height) + yAxe.top;
            ctxPlugin.moveTo(xAxe.left, lineAt);
            ctxPlugin.lineTo(xAxe.right, lineAt);
            ctxPlugin.stroke();

        }
    }
});
```

Does anybody know what I have to change or add within the ctxPlugin?

**EDIT**

I found out the next line increases the width of the line. The zero value has overwritten 'xAxe.left'.

```
ctxPlugin.moveTo(0, lineAt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out using this plugin I am dealing with a CanvasRenderingContext2D object. It is good to be aware of that fact. http://html5index.org/Canvas%20-%20CanvasRenderingContext2D.html displays a list of all the variables/methods this object can deal with. In my case the next lines helped me:

```
ctxPlugin.lineWidth = 1;
ctxPlugin.moveTo(0, lineAt);
```

Hopefully this can also help you customizing something with Chart.js!